# python wand: change text style with draw.text()

Tags: python, imagemagick, wand

I'm using `draw.text()` to draw some text on a canvas. But the function only seem to take 3 parameters x, y, and body so there is no way to specify what font, color, etc. Probably I'm missing something here because this is pretty basic functionality. What am I missing?

Answer (score 10):

With `wand.drawing.Drawing`, you need to build the "context" of the drawing object. Font style, family, weight, color, and much more, can be defined by setting attributes directly on the `draw` object instance.

```py
from wand.image import Image
from wand.color import Color
from wand.drawing import Drawing
from wand.display import display

with Image(width=200, height=150, background=Color('lightblue')) as canvas:
    with Drawing() as context:
        context.fill_color = Color('orange')
        context.stroke_color = Color('brown')
        context.font_style = 'italic'
        context.font_size = 24
        context.text(x=25,
                     y=75,
                     body="Hello World!")
        context(canvas)
        canvas.format = "png"
        display(canvas)
```

[image: change text style with wand.draw]

**But what if your `draw` object already has vector attributes?**

This is where [`Drawing.push()`](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.4.0/wand/drawing.html#wand.drawing.Drawing.push) & [`Drawing.pop()`](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.4.0/wand/drawing.html#wand.drawing.Drawing.pop) can be used to manage your drawing stack.

```py
 # Default attributes for drawing circles
 context.fill_color = Color('lime')
 context.stroke_color = Color('green')
 context.arc((75, 75), (25, 25), (0, 360))
 # Grow context stack for text style attributes
 context.push()
 context.fill_color = Color('orange')
 context.stroke_color = Color('brown')
 context.font_style = 'italic'
 context.font_size = 24
 context.text(x=25,
             y=75,
             body="Hello World!")
 # Return to previous style attributes
 context.pop()
 context.arc((175, 125), (150, 100), (0, 360))
```

[image: text style with context-stack]